# How to set cron job in cpanel

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I am using X10 hosting

Server is https://boru.x10hosting.com

In add cron job i had given

**Command** `/usr/bin/php -q /home/mohanphp/www/quote_bot/sms_cron.php >>/home/mohanphp/www/quote_bot/log/cron_log.txt 2>&1`

I had tried

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/mohanphp/www/quote_bot/sms_cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1

/usr/bin/php -f /home/mohanphp/www/quote_bot/sms_cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I had set cron for every 5 minutes.

Please help me what wrong i did with the command.

Comment: Did you check the error logs? Remove the `>/dev/null` part for a while so you can see the generated output (you will receive it via email).

Comment: error log is empty and i didnt received mail also

Comment: Some hostings have restrictions on how often a cron job can be run (e.g. only every 15 minutes as the "most often"). You should check the docs of your hosting. Also you can try to put your php command in shell script (with redirecting output etc.) and than run this shell script from cron job. It might be easier to debug.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some of my tries :)

The following worked fine in my case:

```
wget -O /dev/null http://example.com/cron/my-cron.php >/dev/null
```

Also the following worked fine (I think this is better if we have 'https://' in the URL):

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/user/public_html/cron/my-cron.php >/dev/null
```

Another one:

```
curl -s http://example.com/cron/my-cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

If you do not wish to receive an email notifying you of a specific cron job, add the following line to the command: `>/dev/null 2>&1`

Ref: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/CronJobs

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this:

`/usr/bin/wget -q -O /dev/null "http://www.mydomain.com/myscript.php" > /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score -1):

I am using this in cPanel, working perfect

```
wget http://site_name/file_location.php
```